# Why is master behind my latest commit

Tags: git

I've been having a bit of trouble with Git, I'm not very experienced with it. I looked at the Version Control tab in Intellij and it turns out the master icon was behind my latest commit even though my latest commit is in my master branch. When I do git checkout master it doesn't checkout the latest commit. I must have done something wrong to make this happen. I never created a new branch or anything. What could be some possible reasons for this?

Comment: Did you commit on a different computer or using the GitHub edit feature? Maybe a screenshot of the version control tab would help to explain.

Comment: I used the same computer and didn't use edit. I fixed it by doing git pull origin master but lost some of my progress but it's alright. I still want to make sure this doesn't happen again though.

Comment: Short of a possible bug in IntelliJ, if you made a commit to the master branch, then Git should be showing this.  You should try to make your question reproducible.

Comment: The thing is I kind of messed around so I can't say exactly what I did. And I had some stuff going on outside so I wasn't fully concentrated. I'll try to reproduce it though

Comment: Not sure if it's possible to do in intellij idea git client, but symptoms sound like it was a commit to a detached head.

Comment: That seems like the case but in my remote repository the commits were part of master. I recently must have done something to detach them. Could rebase separate the branch?

Comment: could you post the output of `git reflog` and `git branch`?

Comment: It sounds like you missed the final step: _sync_. The whole process is _stage_, _commit_, _sync_. Coming from a TFS background this seems to be overcomplicated but I'm getting used to it.

Answer (score 0):

> When I do git checkout master it doesn't checkout the latest commit.

It does checkout the local commit referenced by the local branch master, which can be behind the latest commit pushed.

[Pulling the changes](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sync-with-a-remote-repository.html#pull) from IntelliJ should be enough to sync that master branch once again.

Answer (score 0):

**What you are looking for is a [git-pull](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-pull).**

Doing a [git-pull](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) will bring in changes from the remote repository.

**Command line:**

```
$ git pull
```

This will pull in changes from the remote repository.

**IntelliJ**
On IntelliJ there should be a git menu option to sync with the remote repository.
This is what I found online: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sync-with-a-remote-repository.html#pull

**About git checkout**
[git-checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) only brings out local changes from the branch that you select into the working tree.

*For example*
Suppose you are on `BranchA`, and you run the following

```
$ git checkout BranchB
```

The above will only bring in changes into your working-tree from `BranchB`'s local copy on your machine. If you want to sync this branch with remote (assuming you got this branch from the remote server), you will need to do a git pull.

**Further Notes**
Make sure to commit any unsaved changes before you do a `pull`.

If there are conflicting changes after the pull git will try to auto-merge the changes. If git is unable to merge the changes automatically it will say so and will prompt you to manually merge conflicts. In that case, you need to manually resolve the conflict and then do a commit.